# Get control in code from ControlTemplate By Name

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I have next control template in my WPF app.

```
    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LabelStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"  Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

TextBox "MyTextBlock" is invisible in C# code of window. How can I access to this textblock in code

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685077/how-to-dynamically-access-element-names-in-xaml

Comment: That question seems quite different because it does not involve control templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding your property to the textbox's visibility directly

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding IsFieldCodesEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
```

where BoolToVis is defined as:

```
<Resouces> 
    <loc:BooleanToVisibilityConverter k:key="BoolToVis"/> 
</Resources>
```

Comment: Yes!  The bottom line is that if you are trying to access the TextBox in code in this scenario, you are almost certainly doing something very wrong.  This is a great answer because it shows the right way to do this.  I would give you +10 if I could.

Comment: I like this solution. Pure and understandable. !!

Comment: I do not understand at all.  Your TextBox is not like the original.  IsFieldCodesEnabled is defined where?  In the Window of the control that uses this style?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a similar thing that XAML pages do in the code behind (except for you need to do it in `OnApplyTemplate` override):

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    var MyTextBlock = this.GetTemplateChild("MyTextBlock")
}
```

**EDIT** Just noticed that MyTextblock is actually a TextBox, so casting a `TextBox` to `TextBlock` will cause an exception. Try the updated code.

Comment: İgor it's not work. My ControlTemplate in Window.Resources. I paste your code in my app and set breakpoint to check variable.But MyTextBlock variable stay null. What I make wrong?

Comment: Did you set the style on the label in XAML? Like so: `<Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>`

Comment: Try `(TextBlock)this.FindName("MyTextBlock");`

Comment: I understand it and use correct cast to TextBox but findName method return null

Comment: `GetTemplateChild` seems to work even though MSDN recommends against it. Will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I found some solution for my situation. I just use loaded event of TextBox in my ControlTemplate

```
    private void MyTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
        if (txt!=null)
         {
            Messagebox.Show("It works");
         }

    }
```

But it is not so beautiful solution.

Comment: No! obviously, that is not elegant. In addition to that, can you tell me the need to access that particular textbox so that i can tell you an alternate solution as accessing elements by name from codebehind is hardly recommended.

Comment: I can tell you. I want to hide TextBox is some situation and show it when  I need it. That why  I want to get instance of TextBox for manipulate with his Visibility property.

Comment: You can use bind your visibility property in xaml rather for that using BindingConverter if required. If you could tell me the conditions on which the visibility is dependent, i think i could draw it up clearly.

Comment: I have some static class with static bool property "isFieldCodesEnabled". Before to open window i check value of this property: is true - then I show my textBox, if false I hide it.